# How can I take a partial screenshot when RDP-ing on the remote machine

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, remote-desktop, citrix-receiver

Ok, so the normal way to do what I want to do locally is <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>. I found [these instructions](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ff054acb-908c-4f1e-942b-8b3c0d87d8d1/taking-screenshot-on-remote-desktop-to-show-the-rightclick-submenu?forum=winserverTS)

> To use Windows keyboard shortcuts, follow these steps:

> Open Remote Desktop Connection by clicking the Start button Picture of the Start button, clicking All Programs, clicking Accessories, and then clicking Remote Desktop Connection.

> Click Options, and then click Local Resources.

> Under Keyboard, select On the remote computer to make the remote computer recognize the Windows keyboard shortcuts that you type. (You can also choose In full screen mode only to get the same result as long as you use Remote Desktop Connection in full-screen mode. This is the default setting.)

However this won't work because I have to log into Citrix in order to launch RDP via the file explorer. I was able to make an `.rdp` file this way, so although these settings are not available via right clicking properties of the rdp file, maybe there's someway I can change them by editing it?

I have seen some instructions about other shortcuts involving the `-` key, but I can't seem to get those to work, and they didn't appear to be for windows 10.

I'd use 3rd party software but corporate policy doesn't allow me to install anything not on the approved list.

I have been able to successfully take a full screen screenshot, although I still haven't figured out how to put that in a file :/ .

How can I take a partial screenshot that I can save and edit on my remote workstation?

Comment: Ask if you can use SnagIt. This is an excellent screen capture tool. I can use it to capture and edit any size of screenshot from a host, virtual guest, or remote machine. I have it on my remote machine and can use it from there as well.

Comment: @John I *explicitly* stated that I cannot use 3rd party software.

Comment: Yes I know . But since what I suggested is a top grade pro tool, and will fit your needs, you should consider asking. We try to fill our customers’ needs when this question comes up.

Comment: As you do RDP, what's to stop you from taking a screenshot of *your* screen?

Comment: @John so far all of my requests have fallen on deaf ears, and apparently the process requires a lot of paperwork and months of time.

Comment: @harrymc the problem is that if I take a screenshot of the screen that goes to the laptop, is that I'm not inside the corporate network, which means I can't attach it, or upload it to anything.

Comment: Can you use 3rd party software that doesn't require installation?

Comment: That seems to be a "depends", but I probably am not supposed to, unless it's installing into a runtime, node or java. It's unclear whether a portable app is allowed.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so the answer for me is to use the [Snipping Tool](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/use-snipping-tool-to-capture-screenshots-00246869-1843-655f-f220-97299b865f6b), it can be run from the search box, and appears to do well enough. There's also [Snip and Sketch](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/how-to-take-and-annotate-screenshots-on-windows-10-ca08e124-cc30-2579-3e55-6db63e36fbb9) which appears to be the new thing than <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> actually does, but when I execute it directly, it just exits (or crashes?), who knows what they've done to this machine that things don't actually work right.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using Windows's on-screen keyboard to execute your <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> command:

[image: picture of Windows on-screen keyboard]

For details, including how to enable it, see Microsoft's "[Use the On-Screen Keyboard (OSK) to type](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/use-the-on-screen-keyboard-osk-to-type-ecbb5e08-5b4e-d8c8-f794-81dbf896267a#:%7E:text=in%20tablet%20mode.-,To%20open%20the%20On%2DScreen%20Keyboard,screen%20until%20you%20close%20it.)" support article